# What is DBCC CHECKIDENT current column value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

DBCC CHECKIDENT output includes a "current identity value" and a "current column value". I can see that "current identity value" is the identity that will be assigned to the next row. But what is the "current column value" referring to?

My routine works like this (pseudo):

```
dbcc checkident ('TableA')
set identity_insert on
insert TableA select TableB where status = 'X'
delete TableB where status 'X'
set identity_insert off
dbcc checkident ('TableA')
```

The current identity value of both DBCC statements is the same. The current column value seems to be the highest ID recovered. But what does it mean?

Comment: Have you read this TECHNET article on DBCC CHECKIDENT? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258817(v=sql.80).aspx It sounds like the 'current column value' is the highest identity value that currently exists in the table, like you said. It is just reporting that to you. It allows you to specify a reseed value that is appropriate for the current maximum identity that exists in the table.

Comment: I did. The explanation of the two returned values is not there.

Comment: It seems that the "current" value is actually not the highest but, in my case, the last one inserted with identity_insert.

Comment: It is there. `Execute DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', NORESEED) to determine the current maximum value in the column, and then specify that as the new_reseed_value in a DBCC CHECKIDENT ('table_name', RESEED, new_reseed_value) statement.` and it is also in Aaron Bertrand's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "recovered" - current column value tells you the maximum value in the table. It's meant to show you when the maximum value is *greater* than the value SQL Server assigned last (and from which it determines what it *thinks* it's going to assign next, even if in practice this isn't always true). Example:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
CREATE TABLE dbo.smudge(id INT IDENTITY);
GO
-- insert 11 rows
INSERT dbo.smudge DEFAULT VALUES;
GO 11
DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.smudge'); -- 11, 11
GO
-- delete the largest id
DELETE dbo.smudge WHERE id = 11;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.smudge'); -- 11, 10
GO
-- reseed the table
DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.smudge', RESEED, 1);
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.smudge'); -- 1, 10
GO
-- insert another row
INSERT dbo.smudge DEFAULT VALUES;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.smudge'); -- 11, 11
GO
-- insert a much higher row
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.smudge ON;
INSERT dbo.smudge(id) VALUES(255);
SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.smudge OFF;
GO
DBCC CHECKIDENT('dbo.smudge'); -- 255, 255
GO
DROP TABLE dbo.smudge;
GO
```

Comment: I can check this myself, but what happens if you delete all 11 and then insert 5 with identity_insert turned on? Is the next default identity inserted 12?

Comment: Yes, the next identity_insert would be 12. If you want to delete everything in the table and start over at 1 (or 6 in that case I guess?), then use `TRUNCATE` instead of `DELETE`.

Comment: I need to recover archived records, so I wouldn't ever reseed, just want to make sure that when I re-use an archived identity, then next new identity will not be affected. Thanks for the script, it did the trick on testing and taught me some stuff I didn't know (go 11, for one)